# Proof question about Jeffreys' prior & normal distribution

Tags: self-study, bayesian, normal-distribution, jeffreys-prior

Demonstrate that the Jeffreys' prior for the mean and variance parameters of normally distributed data $x=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n\}$ is given by $p(\theta,\phi)\propto \phi^{-3/2}$.

Comment: This looks like self study - what have you done to attempt to solve this yourself?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, it should be tagged 'self-study'. I think you should give some more background information, regardless. For example, what is $\phi$ and $\theta$

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1: find the square root of the determinant of the Fisher information matrix, and you have your answer. The determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of the diagonal entries.

Hint 2: decide whether the variance or the standard deviation is your scale parameter, and stick with that. If you choose the variance, you're taking derivatives with respect to the variance. Some people write the variance as $\sigma^2$, and take derivatives with respect to $\sigma$; this is incorrect.